# Is there a way to cast to the type passed in a generic function?

Tags: c#, .net, generics, casting

I want to write a generic function, to loop through several different objects, that have one field in common. I want to change this field on all of the objects.

However, I need the types of each of the objects in the generic function.

My code looks like this:

```
UpdateObjects<objectType>(IMyCollection collection) {
    foreach (objectType obj in collection)
    {
        var correctlyTypedObject = (objectType)obj.MakeEditable();
        // Do stuff with correctlyTypedObject
    }
}
```

The MakeEditable() changes the type of the obj, so I need to cast it back.

Is there a way to do this?

I call the function as follows:
`UpdateObjects<userObject>(collection);`

Since I call the function with type `userObject`, I figured you could use that type to cast objects within the function itself. Is this assumption correct?

Comment: Why use `ICollection` when you can have a typed collection of `ICollection<YourType>`?

Comment: Casting is something at **compile-time**. There´s no way to do that when you don´t know the exact type at compile-time. Btw.: your loop allready **does** the casting, no need to do it again.

Comment: ICollection is a self made collection type, has nothing to do with any existing ICollection. Didn't even know that was a thing.

Comment: That´s not the point. The question is: do you know `objectType` at compile-time? Otherweise there´s no use for generics.

Comment: OK, that begs the question: why are you making your own collection type? There's a reason they already exist in the framework.

Comment: I pass ```objectType``` (```userObject``` in my example)  runtime, not before that.

Comment: `// Do stuff with correctlyTypedObject` doesn't make sens ... as `objectType` can be anything

Comment: Well, it´s **executed** at runtime, sure. But the actual type-info is known at **compile-time**, that is you have written it into your code directl: `Update<userType>(collection)`.

Comment: But casting an object to the ```objectType``` I pass in the generic function, is not possible, it seems?

Comment: You don't __pass__ a type parameter in to a generic function, you select (or the runtime creates) a function for that specific type and call that newly created function, and yes, in the concrete version of the function, you can cast to the generic type parameter without issue. In effect, at runtime, you will have multiple `UpdateObjects<someType>` methods created, for each `someType` that is used by your program.

Comment: How are you instantiating a generic method at runtime with a runtime `Type` variable? Are you calling `MakeGeneric`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understand your problem completely, but it seems to me you are looking for what [dynamic](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/types/using-type-dynamic) offers.

Assuming three classes `A,B,C` which all have property `P`.

```
class A { public int P { get; set; } }
class B { public int P { get; set; } }
class C { public int P { get; set; } }
```

Then a function could look like this:

```
private void UpdateObjects(dynamic[] collection)
{
    int newValue = 123456;
    foreach (dynamic obj in collection)
    {
        obj.P = newValue;
    }
}
```

Could be used like this:

```
dynamic[] collection = new dynamic[] {new A(), new B(), new C()};
UpdateObjects(collection);

// Result
foreach (dynamic o in collection)
{
    int p = o.P;
    Debug.WriteLine(p);
}
```